# Waypoint not calling on section

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints, waypoint

I'm currently using jQuery waypoint trying to trigger a waypoint on a section, however, it doesn't work. Not sure if this is due to localhost or what.

My current code is

```
$('.howDoesItWork').waypoint(function() {
    $(".header").css({
      background: 'yellow'
    });
  }, { offset: 1000 });
```

this doesn't work, however, if I do

```
$('body').waypoint(function() {
    $(".howDoesItWork .header").css({
      background: 'yellow'
    });
  }, { offset: 1000 });
```

it works.

I have the code wrapped around `$(document).ready(function()` so I don't see that being the issue.

Answer (score 1):

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

I use Waypoint like this :

```
var infoPage = document.querySelector('.infoPage');
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: infoPage,
  handler: function() {
    infoPage.classList.add('infoReset')
  },
});
```

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jquery, just wrap the entire script inside $(document).ready() like this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 ...
 $('selector').waypoint()
})
```

It worked for me